# Foundation 5 reveal from an appended link

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

I have some troubles to make Reveal work properly from a dynamic link.

This is working fine if the link is loaded with the page. If the link is appended later on, it won't work:

```
<div id="deleteConfirm" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    Delete Confirm Modal
</div>
<a data-modal="deleteConfirm">Test</a>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click','a[data-modal]',function(){
    $(document).foundation();
    $('#deleteConfirm').foundation('reveal', 'open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflow. I assume that you are loading some html using ajax which includes a reveal link

If you have **div#ajax-content** you can use the following javascript

```
$(document).on('replace', '#ajax-content', function (e, new_path, original_path) {
  $(document).foundation('reveal', 'reflow');
});
```